# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException on Toshiba Thrive tab, but not on Samsung Duos smartphone

Tags: android, exception, tabs, smartphone

In "onCreate" method, I have a line of code,

```
Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream) new java.net.URL(url).getContent()), "");
```

When I run it on smartphone(Samsung Duos), it works well. But when I run it on Toshiba Thrive tablet, I get `"android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"` exception.
Why does it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the newer versions of Android since `3.0`, you can't run Network activities on the Main UI thread.
Those get killed automatically, as it leads to a bad user experience anyway.

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
>   networking operation on its main thread.
>
> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or
>   higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do
>   networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily
>   discouraged.

**[NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)**

Run it on a different thread, maybe use [**AsyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

[NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) will come on android OS >=3.0

So always run your web request in an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
    private class BackgroundLoginTask extends
AsyncTask<InputStream, Void, Boolean> {        

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        // do something before..

        // Disable the UI-Elements during the login progress

        pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        editPassword.setEnabled(false);
        editUsername.setEnabled(false);
        btnLogin.setEnabled(false);

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final InputStream... params) {

        //do the network access
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean parsingError) {

        // enable the UI-Elements when the login was successful
        editPassword.setEnabled(true);
        editUsername.setEnabled(true);
        btnLogin.setEnabled(true);


        // hide the progress bar
        pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

In this small example you could see how the AsyncTask works. You could override 3 methods. There is one which is called before you start the background process, one does the access and the third is called after you've done the background process. In my example I disable the UI-Elements and show a progressbar before I do the network access. After the access i enable the UI-Elements and disable the progressbar in the onPostExecute method.

In the following code snipped you can see how you call the AsyncTask.

```
public final void login(final View view) {
    BackgroundLoginTask task = new BackgroundLoginTask();
    task.execute();
}
```

I hope this example could help you.